# D maloc/free alocated container issue

Tags: d

Thanks to support, I can write some simple programs, but, my actual attempt failed due to SIGSEGV. From my point of view, memory are valid allocated via malloc, then, why I access wrong memory?

```
module test.main;
import std.stdio;
import std.c.stdlib;
import std.conv;

class example
{
    int num;
    this()
    {
        writeln("example ctor");
        num = 1000;
    }
    ~this()
    {
        writeln("example dtor");
    }
}

struct simpleVector(T)
{
    T * buffer = null;
    int size = 0;
    this(int _size)
    {
        size = _size;
        buffer = cast(T*)malloc(T.sizeof*size);
        for (int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
           ctor(buffer[i])
        }
    }
    ~this()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
           dtor(buffer[i]);
        }
        size = 0;
        free(buffer);
    }
    void dtor(ref T ob)
    {
        ob.__dtor();
    }
        void ctor(ref T ob)
    {
        ob.__ctor();
    }

};

void main()
{
    simpleVector!example vc = simpleVector!example(5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(This answer is for [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21997402/2) of the question.)

These two lines are wrong:

```
emplace!T(cast(T*)buffer[i*T.sizeof]);
dtor(*(cast(T*)buffer[i*T.sizeof]));
```

`buffer` doesn't hold pointers to objects, but the object data itself. So, get a pointer before casting to `T*`:

```
emplace!T(cast(T*)&buffer[i*T.sizeof]);
dtor(*(cast(T*)&buffer[i*T.sizeof]));
```

(**Update:** nope) <del>Better yet, make `buffer` properly typed:</del>

```
T* buffer = null;
buffer = cast(T*)malloc(T.sizeof*size);
emplace!T(&buffer[i]);
dtor(buffer[i]));
```

(**Update:** nope, see below) <del>Maybe even make `buffer` a D array:</del>

```
T[] buffer;
buffer = (cast(T*)malloc(T.sizeof*size))[0 .. size];
free(buffer.ptr);
```

**Update:**
I missed a crucial detail: `T` is a class type. That means:

- `T.sizeof` is the size of the reference. You need the size of the data, i.e. `__traits(classInstanceSize, T);`.
- `buffer` should **not** be typed `T*` or `T[]`. That would be an array of references. `byte*` or `byte[]` is fine.
- You need to use the `(void[] chunk, auto ref Args args)` overload of `emplace` (others are for non-class types).
- You have to respect alignment.
- `dtor`'s parameter shouldn't be `ref`.

All in all (not 100% sure this is all correct):

```
struct simpleVector(T)
{
    enum instanceSize = __traits(classInstanceSize, T);
    enum padding = instanceSize % std.traits.classInstanceAlignment!T;
    enum paddedInstanceSize = instanceSize + padding;
    byte * buffer = null;
    int size = 0;
    this(int _size)
    {
        size = _size;
        buffer = cast(byte*)malloc(paddedInstanceSize*size);
        for (int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
            emplace!T(buffer[i*paddedInstanceSize .. (i+1)*paddedInstanceSize]);
        }
    }
    ~this()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
           dtor(cast(T) &buffer[i*paddedInstanceSize]);
        }
        size = 0;
        free(buffer);
    }
    void dtor(T ob)
    {
        ob.__dtor();
    }

}
```

You could polish that some more. E.g. by using a `struct Padded {byte[paddedInstanceSize] data;}` for `buffer`'s elements.

Comment: Yeah, no SIGSEGV, but, my constructor isn't called (it isn't shouting example ctor).

Comment: If I write function ctor (looks like dtor) and call ctor(buffer[i]), it invoke constructor (only for first time) but it end with SIGSEGV. What is wrong?

Comment: I missed the peculiarities of class types. Updated the answer.

Comment: The [current version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21997402/3) of the question makes less sense to me than the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21997402/2). It now looks like all you want to malloc is the buffer. But if you don't want to `emplace` the instances, you can just `new` them; no need for `__ctor`/`__dtor` fiddling.

Comment: I try to make "object pool" for alocating and dealocating object.

Comment: how to implement my own emplace function? I try it with calling __ctor() (on reference) but it isn't working great. If I call function (on object constructed with __ctor call), it invokes SIGSEGV...If I use emplace, its work great.